# PHP remove predefined characters from string

Tags: php

I have a script connecting to a mikrotik router and reading traffic stats from it.

The API response gives me output like `<pppoe-0404>` as `$nodename`
then `$nodename=substr($nodename,7,-1);`  strips it down to `0404` by stripping the first 7 and last 1 characters.

The problem occurs if output is `<pppoe-0404-1>`. How do I strip `-1` from the end if it appears?

I tried `$nodename=rtrim($nodename, "-1");` but then all nodes ending with `1` would loose the last digit from name. `0401` would become `040` which is incorrect output.

Comment: try using php  `explode`

Comment: If it's always 4 digits, you could try: `$nodename=substr($nodename,7,4);` getting 4 chars (instead of `$nodename=substr($nodename,7,-1);` which strips the last char)

Answer (score 1):

There might be many other things to take into consideration, but to answer yor question, you could do something like this:

`first check if there was a restart, then:`

```
$nodename =  explode("-", $nodename);
$nodename = $nodename[0];
```